# Connecting to SQL Server Express 2008 from a CE device

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, windows-ce, connection-string

I've developing a .NET Compact Framework app that needs to connect to SQL Server 2008 Express on another machine (Windows 7 x64).

I'm tearing my hair out here - I can ping both ways from the device to the machine etc (although I lose some packets - presumably because at the moment the wireless router is miles away and we don't get much signal down here), but when I try and debug the application on the CE machine it always fails to find SQL Server.

I've tried a variety of different connection strings with no joy.

Here's the connection string I've got at the moment:

```
Data Source=10.0.0.12;Initial Catalog=EMS_Main;User ID=sa;Password=password;
```

Firewall is off.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the exact error message you are receiving?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to post it - I get a System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException that has the message "SQL Server does not exist or access is denied."

Comment: What port is SQL Express set to listen on? Default is 1433 if I recall, but perhaps this instance is configured to listen on a different port. What happens if you specify the port as part of the connection string OR what happens if you use the instance name instead of the IP address?

Comment: Also, you could try installing SSMS on the remote machine and see if you can connect from SSMS to the SQL Express instance.

Comment: The plot thickens - if I have SMSS open on the server, the CE device will talk to it quite happily. The second that SMSS is exited, no connection...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your SQL Express instance [set up to accept remote connections](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2008/09/17/enabling-remote-sql-express-2008-network-connections-on-vista.aspx)?  Do you have WIndows Firewall turned off, or allowing the port access for SQL Server?

Comment: Yes it's set up for remote connections. Firewall is off, as stated in my original post.